# Form not writing to database the right way

Tags: php, mysql

Heey,

I am busy with a form that has to insert its value into a database (mysql). The form has to write to two tables called address and person. The persons information needs to write to person and its address has to write to the address table. However when I press submit, it will say everything went successfully BUT it doesn't store information in person only in address.

In the database person_address is linked to address_id in a later state I will create a detail form where the "admin" can select city OR state and it will show all the persons in the city and state.

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]
[image: picture 3]

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, person_email,      person_phonenumber, person_cv)
VALUES     ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[telephone]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[cv]')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO address (address_street, address_housenumber,     address_zipcode, address_city, address_state)
VALUES
('$_POST[straat]','$_POST[huisnummer]','$_POST[postcode]','$_POST[stad]','$_POST[provincie]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $URL="http://localhost:8080/Website/bedankt.php";  

header ("Location: $URL");  
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: are there really spaces in here? `$_PO    ST`. check for errors in PHP for your POST arrays for the HTML form you didn't post. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - and the `cv` looks to be file-related.

Comment: Plus, it's only writing in the last one, because you overwrote the first one. Use 2 seperate queries, or use multi_query.

Comment: There are not lol, sorry everytime I upload code it does this.... Also the links to images I am linking to are not working.

Comment: Here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php that's what you need to use, as per my comment up there. That's why only the second one works. You're also open to a massive SQL injection here.

Comment: *"Also the links to images I am linking to are not working."* - that'd be a seperate question altogether, and your posted code doesn't support that.

Comment: I looked at it still not really clear for me... I uploaded some pictures of my database 

PS: I am new to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you overwrite your `$sql` variable without executing it. Also, consider sanitizing and binding your `$_POST` variables with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Additionally you can use `mysqli->insertid` to capture the auto_increment `address_id` in `address` table and use it in subsequent `person` append query to maintain relationships between both tables. Of course you need to reverse the order of the sql statements.

```
// DATABASE CONNECTION
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// ADDRESS APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO address (address_street, address_housenumber, 
                                             address_zipcode, address_city, address_state)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $straat, $huisnummer, $postcode, $staad, $provincie);

$straat = htmlspecialchars($_POST[straat]);
$huisnummer = htmlspecialchars($_POST[huisnummer]);
$postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST[postcode]);
$stad = htmlspecialchars($_POST[stad]);
$provincie = htmlspecialchars($_POST[provincie]);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

// CAPTURE LAST INSERTED address_id
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

// PERSON APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, 
                                            person_email, person_phonenumber,
                                            person_cv, person_address)
                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email, $cv, $last_id);

$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST[firstname]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST[lastname]);
$telephone = htmlspecialchars($_POST[telephone]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST[email]);
$cv = htmlspecialchars($_POST[cv]);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === TRUE) {
    $URL="http://localhost:8080/Website/bedankt.php";  
    header ("Location: $URL");  
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks!, Alright this is working however... Could be a small thing BUT in my database the field address_id has a relation with person_address. This means table information of address is connected to a person by its address_id which is connected to person_address in person table. BUT in my database under person_address it says NULL so there is no data. 

When I'll make my detail page... The "admin" can select a city or state and it will show the person who lives in the city or state.

Later I'll use Javascript/Ajax to check the fields if they are filled in but that's for later.

Comment: Did you see my note and code line using `$last_id`. Are you saying `$mysqli->insert_id` did not work? Notice it is used in last column of `person` append query, mapped to `person_address`.

Comment: I did see it, but I think it's not working I'll test it soon by making the detail page... All it says in my database is person_address = NULL

Comment: Apologies. See update where the named [mysqli object](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp) is used: `$last_id = $conn->insert_id;` not `$mysqli`.

Comment: Can you help me with one other thing? I hope you do not mind and hope it's a quick fix [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750018/how-do-i-upload-a-file-within-a-database-with-1-or-more-relations)

Answer (score 2):

As Fred -ii- already said, you are overwriting the first query by writing the second query to the same variable. To solve the problem you should use two queries.

```
$sql1 = "...";

$sql2 = "...";

if($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE && $conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
   ...
}
```

Also, there is SQL injection possible because you don't escape the `$_POST` parameters. This allows other people to execute malicious SQL on your server. You should have a look at [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).