# How do I upload a file within a database with 1 or more relations

Tags: php, mysql

I created a form where people can upload their personal information and resume. Now my database has three tables called person, address and cv. address and cv both has a relation with person. When I fill in the form and look in my database the person > address is correct however it doesnt save the resume(path) in the database at all. Also the cv_id is shown in person as a NULL. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

My upload.php (file)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $filetmp = $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
  $filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
  $filetype = $_FILES["cv"]["type"];
  $filepath = "files/".$filename;

  move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO cv (cv_name,cv_path,cv_type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Here is my function.php which only uploads person and address information. My form has two actions to function.php and upload.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// ADDRESS APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO address (address_street, address_housenumber, 
                                         address_zipcode, address_city, address_state)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $straat, $huisnummer, $postcode, $stad, $provincie);

$straat = htmlspecialchars($_POST['straat']);
$huisnummer = htmlspecialchars($_POST['huisnummer']);
$postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST['postcode']);
$stad = htmlspecialchars($_POST['stad']);
$provincie = htmlspecialchars($_POST['provincie']);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

// CAPTURE LAST INSERTED address_id
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

// PERSON APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, 
                                        person_email, person_phonenumber,
                                        person_cv, person_address)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $cv, $last_id);

$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$telephone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['telephone']);


// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === TRUE) {
$URL="http://localhost:8080/Website/bedankt.php";  
header ("Location: $URL");  
} else {
echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="firstname" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="lastname" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achternaam" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="straat" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Straat" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="huisnummer" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Huisnummer" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="postcode" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="stad" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stad" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <select name="provincie"  id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Provincie" required>
                        <option value="Drenthe">Drenthe</option>
                        <option value="Flevoland">Flevoland</option>
                        <option value="Friesland">Friesland</option>
                        <option value="Gelderland">Gelderland</option>
                        <option value="Groningen">Groningen</option>
                        <option value="Limburg">Limburg</option>
                        <option value="Noord-Brabant">Noord-Brabant</option>
                        <option value="Noord-Holland">Noord-Holland</option>
                        <option value="Overijssel">Overijssel</option>
                        <option value="Utrecht">Utrecht</option>
                        <option value="Zeeland">Zeeland</option>
                        <option value="Zuid-Holland">Zuid-Holland</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="cv" id="cv" class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="CV" name="cv">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-form" name="submit" value="Solliciteer"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

action.php:

```
<?php
  include('functie.php');
  include('upload.php');
?>
```

Database:
[image: picture]

Maybe there is a way my file upload can be in my function.php.

Comment: Pretty obvious thing to ask but could you paste your html form code as well?

Comment: added my form. Action.php goes to a file which contains the double action to upload.php and function.php

Comment: And what's the action.php? I mean the content. There is no point to make it complicated, you could do it all inside one .php file (action.php for example).

Comment: added my action.php, My function.php is working like a charm so I do not want to change anything on this. However adding the file upload would be great. But if the file upload can be in upload.php that would just be perfect for me.

Comment: Did you find it? As I mentioned you don't define $cv and you try to call it, that's why you get errors and null value is inserted in db. There's also problem with your logic, you fill in details for person and you try to fill it with id that doesn't exist at the time of executing that query.

Comment: I see what you mean, if there a way of adding my upload.php code to function.php the same way address is filled in onlt than for cv. I am new to PHP so still learning how everything works.

Comment: I wrote you an edit. First thing you shouldn't be calling $cv if you haven't defined it anywhere. Create new entry without cv_id and add it later once you have said id. Obviously you cannot use it if it doesn't exist. Then in your upload, at the end get the id and put it where you need it in person table. Problem I see here is your logic and foreign keys, you are probably referencing cv_id in person.person_cv so probably you won't be able to make an INSERT INTO with that field empty. On the other hand you will realize the error once you understand it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in upload.php file on line 24.

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Keep in mind mysql extension is deprecated and it was removed in recent php ver. 7. You shouldn't be using it in your code.

EDIT.
Your current db logic is flawed but who am I to judge you? If you want to do it as you have it now you have to do the following changes.

In function.php modify the INSERT INTO and remove $cv from it.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, person_email, person_phonenumber, person_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $last_id);
```

btw in your original code it's sssssi, this is also an error as your id is probably an integer just like the address id.

In upload.php before you close the `<?php` tag add following line:

```
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Now update the table "person" putting that id into person_cv field.

EDIT2.
Code formatting fails as always...

EDIT3.
I thought you will move it around a little bit and try it yourself. Here is another solution, even simpler.

Look at your files. In action.php change

```
include('function.php');
include('upload.php');
```

to

```
include('upload.php');  
include('functie.php');
```

Now upload.php gets processed first which means that at the end of the upload.php file you can add `$cv = $conn->insert_id;` (right before php closing tag).

Now the variable $cv which you use in function.php exists therefore you can use it and your original insert query will work without inserting NULL values into your db:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, person_email, person_phonenumber, person_cv, person_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $cv, $last_id);
```

Comment: This is not for long term use... I tried the code and it is uploading the file to the database. However the cv_id which has a relation with person_cv in my table still shows NULL and when I go to the detail-page it is not showing the file/path. I added a picture of my database above.

Comment: That is solution to your problem, it uploads the file and correctly fills up the corresponding database fields which didn't work earlier. What are you trying to put in person_cv field? Look at your code and echo it, it's null.

Comment: I could be wrong... But is there a way to insert my file as a statement like the table address?

Comment: You mean in the same file? Or you want to upload it to database instead of storing it on server? You can do both but saving files in db is not a good idea, hurts performance.

Comment: Well... I would like to save the path where my file is on my server to be uploaded to the database... So it will say... www.test.nl/files/test.pdf <- example. However it is just saving the directory name and file name. 

Like address_id has a relation with person_address. I want cv_id to be connected to person_cv... In function.php there is says capture the last added id and put the id (in this case address_id) in person_address... Now I want the same thing to happen with cv_id. So the uploaded file as the address is connected the a person

Comment: So when I open my detail page... the file link which the person has uploaded should be under CV.

Comment: I added you another edit. As for what you are asking I think you should create a new question as this one will be very chaotic trying to solve the problems you no longer need solved. You can add your domain name to the field in db and save files like www.test.nl/files/$filename or when selecting it from db change it into a hyperlink for example "<a href='www.test.nl/files/'" . $filename . ">cv</a" something like that. Anyways you should have 1 table instead of 3. All the data relates to same 1 person, there is no need to create extra tables.

Comment: I would have done it different if I could but It's for a project which has some needs like: tables has to have two relations..etc..etc. Alright it is working now! How ever in my detail page it is showing the cv_id and not the path... But I will create a new question for this  Thanks for helping! Hope I didn't gave you a headache haha.

Comment: No problem. You can easily change that modifying your SELECT (SELECT cv_path instead of SELECT cv_id). Since you are probably doing homework it looks like your professor wanted you to use JOINs

Comment: Well there is no need for using joins... But this is for my exams and I want to add extra's + good coding. So on my certificate I can get a honors ( don't know if it's called like that in english)